# Is There a Way to Fetch a Type Attribute in An Ecto Query

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an Ecto Schema with payments containing an amount field. That field's type is the Money.Ecto.Composite.Type from the ex_money package(v. 5.12.3). The query is:

```
query =
      from(
        payment in Payment,
        where: payment.amount.currency_code() == ^currency
      )
```

This raises:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) cannot fetch field `currency_code` from `payment.amount`. Can only fetch fields from:

  * sources, such as `p` in `from p in Post`
  * named bindings, such as `as(:post)` in `from Post, as: :post`
  * parent named bindings, such as `parent_as(:post)` in a subquery
```

Is there a way to access the attribute and not have Ecto search for a field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
currency = "USD" # atom doesn't work

query =
  from(
    p in Payment,
    where: fragment("(?).amount.currency_code = ?", p, ^currency)
  )
```

Note that currency must be a string but of course you can always use `to_string` if you have an atom.

The reason this works is because it uses the Postgres syntax for [accessing composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING).